# Transforming this serie to a definite integral.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-sum

Basically i need to simplify the following summation: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{cos(nx)}{n^2}$$
As far as i know this summation is equal to 
$$\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{\pi x}{4}+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$ when $[0\le x \le 2\pi]$. Now for the project I'm trying to calculate this for the value of $x$ is never included in such interval. So, given that $cos(x) = cos(x +2\pi k)$ i can actually solve this equation by changing the variable to $y=x-2\pi k$ and simplifying with this. But the resulting equation is an equation with 2 variables, $x$ and $k$, that ain't the result i was looking for (i know as well that $k$ is technically not a variable since you can actually find her, but to do so you need to use modulo which has no math equation and therefore is not the thing i was looking for).

So the alternative i have is to convert such summation in a definite integral, i guess. I've spent few hours looking for an actual method to do so without any result (since I'm a computer engineer, not a mathematician, and I've never had to study deeply calculus). I was wondering if you guys can actually point me to the right direction on this. To actually give you more infos about that my summation is in the form $$2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{cos(nxm)}{n^2 m^2}$$ where $m$ is a generic multiplication factor. 
Ultimately I apologize for my English but understand it's not my first language.

Comment: Is $k$ guaranteed to be an integer?

Comment: Well i guess if $k$ is not an integer you can't write $$cos(x) = cos(x+2\pi k)$$

Comment: Is it possible to use$$\frac 1a=\int\limits_0^{\infty}dt\, e^{-at}$$for $\Re(a)>0$?

Comment: @FelixMarin you're right I've made a mistake in writing that: the summation starts at $n=1$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = \color{red}{1}}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{nx} \over n^{2}} & =
\Re\sum_{n = \color{red}{1}}^{\infty}{\pars{\expo{\ic x}}^{n} \over n^{2}} =
\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\pars{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic\braces{x/\bracks{2\pi}}}} +
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{-2\pi\ic\braces{x/\bracks{2\pi}}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\bracks{-\,{\pars{2\pi\ic}^{2} \over 2!}
\,\mrm{B}_{2}\pars{x \over 2\pi}}\,,\qquad\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{{x \over 2\pi} \in \left[0,1\right)} & \mbox{if} & \ds{\Im\pars{x} \geq 0}
\\[2mm]
\ds{{x \over 2\pi} \in \left(0,1\right]} & \mbox{if} & \ds{\Im\pars{x} < 0}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions).
>   $\ds{\mrm{B}_{n}}$ is a [Bernoulli Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials).
>   [Note that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Explicit_expressions_for_low_degrees)
>   $\ds{\mrm{B}_{2}\pars{z} = z^{2} - z + {1 \over 6}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = \color{red}{1}}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{nx} \over n^{2}} & =
\pi^{2}\bracks{\pars{x \over 2\pi}^{2} - {x \over 2\pi} + {1 \over 6}} =
\bbx{{1 \over 4}\,x^{2} - {\pi \over 2}\,x + {\pi^{2} \over 6}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is now super-interesting. Since i know nothing about Polylogarythms and Bernoulli Polynomials, can you give me some advice on books that a computer engeneer could understand on the argument? much appreciated.

Comment: @LynCassidy I suggests you start with the $\texttt{Wikipedia}$ links I provided in the answer.

Comment: Just a quick question: how can you justify the polylogarythm conversion to the point  $$\Re{Li_2 (e^{ix})}$$ if $e^{ix} = cos(x)+i\cdot sin(x)$ which means $|e^{ix}| = 1$ for any given x. That might be a problem because 1 is outside the upper boundary of the polylogarythm.

Comment: Felix Marin could you explain better what you've done here? I can't understand the third to fourth passage. Where you convert the Real part of the dilog to a sum of two different dilogs. Are you using real part function?

Comment: @LynCassidy Yes. Because $\displaystyle\Re\left(z\right) = {1 \over 2}\,\left(z + \bar{z}\right)$. The relation between the $\mathrm{Li}_{s}$ and  $\texttt{Bernoulli Polynomial}$ is given in the cited link ( Jonqui$\mathrm{\grave{e}}$re's Inversion Formula ). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the content of your first paragraph...

Let $x = \hat{x}+2\pi k$ for $k$ an integer.  In your sum, $n$ is also an integer.  Then \begin{align*}
\cos(nx) &= \cos(n(\hat{x}+2\pi k))  \\
    &= \cos(n\hat{x}+2\pi k n)  \\
    &= \cos(n\hat{x})  \text{,}
\end{align*}
because $kn$, the product of two integers, is also an integer.  Consequently, the value of $k$ has no effect on the sum of your series.

Comment: That's true, the problem is not the effect k has on my summation but the effect it has on the resulting identity, for I get, as written above, an equation with 2 variables: $$\frac{(x-2\pi k)^2}{2} - \frac{\pi(x-2\pi k)}{4} + \frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$

Comment: Replace $x$ with $\hat{x}$ at the outset, then there are no $k$s at any subsequent point.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. I mean from a general prospective what you say might be true, but unfortunately the final result is not the correct one. I really appreciated the answers tho, thanks.

Comment: @LynCassidy : Could you demonstrate that the final result is incorrect in your Question?  At this point, I cannot guess why your work convinces you the final result is not the correct one.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't give you the smaller details, but if i didn't misunderstand your previous comment the outcome should be simply $$\frac{\hat x^2}{2}-\frac{\pi \hat x}{4} + \frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$. I got a difference of two of these summations in my equation. Simplifying without $k$ reduces my equation to simply $x$, which is wrong. On this you'll have to trust me. 
In case i actually misunderstood your comment please give me an explicit example.

Comment: @LynCassidy : Nothing in your most recent comment makes any sense to me.  If you won't show what you mean, I don't see how I can help you.  I see that you get the same answer when you write the hats, there is no difference of $2$, and there is no simplification ending at $x$.

Comment: As I already told you: I can't give you the smaller details. Also because the whole question is not the one you're answering to.

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to based on a false understanding.  Your first paragraph claims that you cannot remove $k$, which you have demonstrated that you can.  Avoiding the obvious [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in your question, I am addressing the false understanding.

Comment: Let's start over again: basically i have the above identity $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{cos(nx)}{n^2} = \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{\pi x}{2} +\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$ which is correct only for $[0 \le x \le 2 \pi]$. Now to get that work, since my $x$ is never included in that interval, i change my variable to $y = x - 2\pi k$ for, as said above, the cosine doesn't change. Then you told me "Replace $x$ with $\hat x$ at the outset, then there are no $k$s at any subsequent point". Which i understood as "You can operate that identity without the $2\pi k$". False.
Write me down some explicit example please.

Comment: You have already shown that this equation holds for any $x$.  The only feature of $x$ that affects this sum is $x \pmod{2\pi}$, which you have already shown.

Comment: Where did i show that this equation holds for any $x$? I actually said the opposite, declaring that the result of the whole equation (on which, again, you'll have to trust me), is not correct if no $k$ is included in the identity. 
As i already stated the problem with $x (mod 2 \pi)$ has no equation so i can't really use it in this project. That's why i was asking for the conversion of the summation to an integral.

Comment: Let $x$ be any real number and $\hat{x}$ be the least nonnegative residue of $x$ modulo $2\pi$.  You have already shown $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2} = \frac{\hat{x}^2}{4} - \frac{\pi \hat{x}}{2} + \frac{\pi^2}{6}  \text{.}$$  The mystery to me is why you refuse to understand that you have shown this.