# Requesting basic explanation of the Lagrange inversion theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, lagrange-inversion

I'm interested in the Lagrange inversion theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Theorem_Statement), despite several attempts on different pdfs, on this site and on wikipedia, (checked already its bibliography, i could reach just Abramowitz's Handbook on mathematical functions, that, unfortunately, is not exhaustive on the argument). So I'm asking you guys to explain to me this theorem in as simple words as you can. I'm expecially interested in the "reversion of serie" aspect (quoting from wikipedia). Thank you a lot

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking (at least not to me).  Do you want an explanation of the statement of the theorem?  What part of it is not clear to you?  Do you know that an analytic function is locally one-to-one at a point where it's derivative doesn't vanish?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Lagrange inversion theorem in a nutshell.**

---

Assume to have a holomorphic function which is $z+o(z)$ in a neighbourhood of the origin, like 
$$\sin(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \tag{1}$$
and to want to compute the coefficients of the Maclaurin series of its inverse function $\arcsin(z)$.
Say the coefficient of $z^7$. Well, by Cauchy's integral formula

$$[z^7]\arcsin(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\varepsilon}\frac{\arcsin(z)}{z^8}\,dz \tag{2}$$
and something nice happens$^{(*)}$ if we enforce the substitution $z=\sin u$ in the RHS of $(2)$. The simple contour around the origin $|z|=\varepsilon$ is mapped into a similar (homeomorphic) simple contour around the origin by a conformal map, hence
$$ [z^7]\arcsin(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|u|=\varepsilon}\frac{u\cos(u)}{\sin(u)^8}\,du \tag{3}$$
and the problem boils down to evaluating the residue of $\frac{u\cos u}{\sin(u)^8}$ at the origin, which is a pole of order $7$ for such a function. In particular
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{u=0}\frac{u\cos u}{\sin(u)^8} = \lim_{u\to 0}\frac{1}{6!}\frac{d^6}{du^6}\left(u^7\cdot \frac{u\cos u}{\sin(u)^8}\right)=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{1}{7!}\frac{d^6}{du^6}\left(\frac{u}{\sin u}\right)^7=\frac{5}{112}\tag{4}$$
and the whole tour proves a connection between the Maclaurin coefficients of $\arcsin$ and the derivatives of $\left(\frac{u}{\sin u}\right)^k$ at the origin.

---

Now you might wonder if to compute the derivatives at the origin of $\left(\frac{u}{f(u)}\right)^k$ for some holomorphic $f(u)=u+o(u)$ is a simple task. Well, in general it is not. For instance the Maclaurin series of $\arcsin$ can be computed with considerably fewer efforts by applying the extended binomial theorem to $\frac{d}{du}\arcsin(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$. On the other hand something really nice is produced by this approach by considering $f(u)=u e^u$, i.e. the Maclaurin series of the Lambert $W$ function:
$$ W(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} n^{n-1}}{n!} x^n\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^n}=\color{red}{1} \tag{!}$$
and the crucial part of the argument $(*)$ can be used for finding the Maclaurin series of $\arcsin^2$, $\arcsin^3$, $\arcsin^4$ etcetera, leading to some non-trivial hypergeometric identities.

---

A concise form of the statement and another example.

> **Lagrange's inversion formula**. If $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of the origin, such that $f(z)=z+o(z)$ as $z\to 0$, we have
>   $$ f^{-1}(z) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n}\cdot [z^{n-1}]\left(\frac{z}{f(z)}\right)^n$$
>   where $[z^m]g(z)$ stands for the coefficient of $z^m$ in the Maclaurin series of $g(z)$.

More generally, if $f,h$ are holomorphic functions in a neighbourhood of the origin and $f(z)=z+o(z)$,
$$ h(f^{-1}(z))=h(0)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n}\cdot [z^{n-1}]\left(h'(z)\cdot\left(\frac{z}{f(z)}\right)^n\right).$$

Another celebrated application is given by Catalan numbers. It is straightforward to prove in a combinatorial fashion that they fulfill 
$ C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} C_k C_{n-k}$, hence their ordinary generating function multiplied by $z$ is given by the inverse function of $f(z)=z-z^2$. By Lagrange's inversion formula

$$ f^{-1}(z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n}[z^{n-1}]\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^n $$
and by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) $\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n}}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{m+n-1}{m}z^n$, hence
$$ f^{-1}(z) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1} $$
and
$$ C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}.$$

---

**Ref**. [*A ridiculously simple and explicit implicit function theorem*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0069), A.D. Sokal, 2009.

Comment: This is such a complete answer that I'm not fully understanding it yet, so, for the great effort, your answer as been flagged as the correct one.

Comment: Do you mind writing me down a second example please?

Comment: @LynCassidy: which part(s) is(/are) difficult to grasp? Anyway, I have added a concise statement and a further example.

Comment: (anche io sono italiano, continuerò a scriverle in inglese per permettere anche ad altri di leggere il suo commento) 
Well first of all, since I'm not a math student, I don't fully understand the meaning of the Cauchy integral formula, I'm gonna take it for granted. I fully understood the integral result of the substitution at step (3) but i can't understand why the whole problem boils down to evaluating the integrand function so i can't link the final result $\frac{5}{112}$ to the main problem.

Comment: keep in mind I would love to use this theorem to normalize a summation like the following: $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{cos(nx)}{n^2}$$
On which I've already tried evaluating the dilog, with no results, as suggested in a question i asked before (for info: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705004/transforming-this-serie-to-a-definite-integral/2705315?noredirect=1#comment5613633_2705315)

Comment: @LynCassidy: Cauchy's integral formula / the residue theorem is essential in Complex Analysis *and* in the proof of Lagrange's inversion theorem, I am not aware of any proof which avoids it. May I ask you what is the original purpose of your investigation about the Lagrange inversion formula? (Lieto di incontrare un connazionale, in ogni caso).

Comment: You do not need Lagrange's inversion formula for computing $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2} = \text{Re}\,\text{Li}_2(e^{ix}).$$ Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ is the Fourier series of the sawtooth-wave, $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2} $$ is a continuous and piecewise-quadratic function. See Bernoulli polynomials.

Comment: Unfortunately i already did. The output result obtained thanks to the identity $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{cos(nx)}{n^2} = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2} + \frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$
unfortunately gives me a two-variables function that has infinite solutions.
This because my $x$ is never included in the domain of such identity so i have to proceed by analytic continuation by using the variable $x - 2k \pi$ instead of simply $x$, such that $k$ is the second variable I'm looking for. You might say that k is easily computable with modulo, but for my purpose i can't use modulo since it has no equation.

Comment: I do not understand the "*has infinite solutions*" and "*I can't use $\text{mod}$*" parts. $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$$ is the $2\pi$-periodic extension of the function which equals $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{x(2\pi-x)}{4}$ over $[0,2\pi]$. No manipulation will ever change this.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Extraordinary nice presentation. (+1)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Maybe it should [be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5Bbinom%28m%2Bn-1%2Cm%29+eulergamma%5Em%2C%7Bm%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D)  $\sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{m+n-1}{m}z^m$? Then we take $m=n-1$ as the series coefficients after “hence”. Right?