# Finding convergence or divergence of a complex series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the convergence of the following series:
$$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}i^n$$
I have tried applying the criteria of the n+1th over nth term:
$$lim_{n->\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}i^{n+1}\frac{n^n}{n!i^n}\right|=lim_{n->\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}i\right|$$
$$=lim_{n->\infty}\left|\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n-1}}\right|$$
But how can I evaluate this limit?

Comment: Try with its rediprocal... Besides you should start with $(n+1)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your exponent on the denominator of $a_{n+1}.$ You should have

$\left| \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|=\left|\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}i^{n+1}\left(\dfrac{n^n}{n!i^n}\right)\right|$.

Then you are left with

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n.$

Comment: The arrow can be realized by \to

Answer (score 1):

That is a *nice* series. By the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741644/requesting-basic-explanation-of-the-lagrange-inversion-theorem/2741758#2741758) we have 
$$ W(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^{n-1}}{n!}x^n $$
where $W$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), i.e. the inverse of $xe^x$ in a neighbourhood of the origin. Since the only stationary point of $xe^x$ occurs at $x=-1$, the radius of convergence of the above series is $\frac{1}{e}$. This radius of convergence is unaffected by the substitution $x\mapsto -x$ or by differentiation. This leads to the fact that

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!}x^n = \frac{-W(-x)}{1+W(-x)} $$
holds for any $|x|<\frac{1}{e}$, and the LHS is the inverse function of $\frac{x}{x+1}e^{-\frac{x}{x+1}}$ in a neighbourhood of the origin.