# Generating function for the sequence $a_n = c_n + c_{n-1} + c_{n-2} +c_{n-3} +... + c_0$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $c_n$ be the Catalan sequence. Give the generating function for the sequence $$a_n = c_n + c_{n-1} + c_{n-2} +c_{n-3} +... + c_0.$$

The answer says that "Let $C(q)$ be the generating function for the Catatlan sequence. Use the relation $A(q) = C(q)(1+q+q^2+…) = C(q) \frac{1}{1−q}$". How is this relation obtained?

Comment: When you multiply two power series $\sum A_nx^n$ and $\sum B_nx^n$ you get a series $\sum C_nx^n$ that satisfies $C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}A_kB_{n-k}$. So, if $A_n=c_n$ and $B_n=1$ you get $C_n$  equal to your $a_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $f(x)$ is an analytic function in the open unit disk such that
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} c_n x^n $$
we have
$$ \frac{f(x)}{1-x}=f(x)\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n = \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k\right)x^n$$
for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$, due to the Cauchy product/convolution. In our case, $c_n=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}$, we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}, $$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-4z}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$
for any $x$ such that $|x|<\frac{1}{4}$ (as an alternative, we have the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2741758/44121)). As a consequence,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{2k}{k}}{k+1}=[x^n]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x(1-x)}=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}+[x^n]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2(1-x)}.$$

Comment: Convergence is not needed in the algebraic equations in the first sentence, actually anywhere in the argument (as long as $\int_{0}^{x}$ is interpreted as antiderivative). They are true in the [Krull $(x)$-adic topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_of_a_ring#Krull_topology), which is the one used to work with formal power series.